# Zend DB Union Error

Tags: mysql, database, zend-framework

I have two query:

```
$select1 = $this->select()
    ->from(array('o'=>'table1'), array('*', 'o.field2 AS shared'))
    ->where('field4= ?', $input);

$select2 = $this->select()
    ->from(array('i'=>'table2'), array('*', 'ch.field1 AS shared'))
    ->where('ch.field5= ?', $input);
```

Both query works successfully. However, it does not work with the following union function even with shared parameter name. How come?

```
//Merge both query
$selectboth = $this->select()
    ->union(array($select1, $select2))
    ->order('shared');

$obj = $this->dbo->fetchRow($selectboth);
```

I am suspecting my fetchRow is the one causing this error in fetching.

Comment: can you please share table structure for union the column count and their datatypes in both select queries should be same

Comment: What it meas by column count? Different table has different number of rows. Datatype is the same

Comment: table1 has 6 columns. Table2 has 11 columns

Comment: you cannot perform union using select * then .. see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: I see. What is the rational behind this?

Comment: You can print your sql using echo $selectboth; . check is it sql error or not.

Answer (score 0):

if you have number of column same in both sql so you can  ran into this issue:

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-4338

for example:

```
$select_q1 = $db->select()->...;
$select_q2 = $db->select()->...;

$main_select = $db->select()->union( array(  '('.$select_q1 .')',  '('.$select_q2 .')' ) );
```